# How to convert the total supported memory using the Win32_ComputerSystem class

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, wmi

i'm making a program to monitor hardware components and I am trying to get the RAM capacity of the desktop using the WMI `Win32_ComptuterSystem` class. I managed to get the amount of total RAM but it is displayed in bits instead of GB, I know i have to make a conversion but I have no idea how to go about it.

```
private void GetRamCapacity()
{
    var wmi = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
    var providers = wmi.GetInstances();

    foreach (var provider in providers)
    {
        var ramCapacity = Convert.ToInt32(provider["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);

        lblRAMCapacity.Text = ramCapacity.ToString();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Just divide the capacity by 1024 to get KB, 1024^2 to get MB, and 1024^3 to get GB.  You'll need to use something other than an Int32 for storing the value as it will only hold capacities up to ~2.1GB.  Also to let you know that the memory value returned is in bytes not bits.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [TotalPhysicalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) returns an **`UInt64`** value.
Convert it to `ulong` instead of `Int32`. Also, the value is expressed in **`Bytes`**:

But you should probably use the value returned by the `Capacity` property of the [Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) class. The `Capacity` value is provided per Memory Bank.

The reason is explained in a note:

> Be aware that, under some circumstances, this property may not return
> an accurate value for the physical memory. For example, it is not
> accurate if the BIOS is using some of the physical memory.

From [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getphysicallyinstalledsystemmemory):

> The BIOS and some drivers may reserve memory as I/O regions for
> memory-mapped devices, making the memory unavailable to the operating
> system and applications.

The sum of the values returned by **`Win32_PhysicalMemory.Capacity`** is the same value returned by **`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory`** (the latter is expressed in kilobytes).
A machine must have the [SMBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) feature available (Windows XP and later), otherwise these functions won't return a value.

An example:

```
ulong totalMemory = WMIGetTotalPhysicalMemory();
string memory = $"{totalMemory / Math.Pow(1024, 3):N2} GB";
```

The **`WMIGetTotalPhysicalMemory()`** method uses the `WMI` `Win32_PhysicalMemory` class per-bank `Capacity` value, summing each bank's installed memory size.

```
public static ulong WMIGetTotalPhysicalMemory()
{
    var mScope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{Environment.MachineName}\root\CIMV2");
    var mQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
    mScope.Connect();

    ulong installedMemory = 0;
    using (var moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, mQuery))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject moCapacity in moSearcher.Get()) {
            installedMemory += (UInt64)moCapacity["Capacity"];
        }
    }
    return installedMemory;
}
```

A comparison method using **`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()`**:
(This value and the value returned by `WMIGetTotalPhysicalMemory` must be the same)

```
 ulong totalMemory = WinAPIGetTotalPhysicalMemory();
```

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out ulong MemInKilobytes);

public static ulong GetTotalPhysicalInstalledMemory()
{
    ulong totalMemory = 0UL;
    bool result = GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out totalMemory);
    if (!result) totalMemory = 0UL;
    return totalMemory * 1024;
}
```

If `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` fails, `totalMemory` will be `0`.
This function fails if the SMBIOS data is not considered valid or it's less than the value returned by the [GlobalMemoryStatusEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex) function.
In this case, GetLastError will return `ERROR_INVALID_DATA = 13`.

`GlobalMemoryStatusEx` returns a [**`MEMORYSTATUSEX`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-_memorystatusex) structure which references the current state of both physical and virtual memory, plus the approximate percentage of physical memory that is in use.
Note that these values are volatile an will change between calls: the Memory status changes constantly.
See the MSDN notes about the meaning of these values.

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX memoryStatus = GetSystemMemoryStatus();
```

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class MEMORYSTATUSEX
{
    public uint dwLength;
    /// <summary> Number between 0 and 100 that specifies the approximate percentage of physical memory that is in use (0 indicates no memory use and 100 indicates full memory use). </summary>
    public uint dwMemoryLoad;
    /// <summary> Total size of physical memory, in bytes. </summary>
    public ulong ullTotalPhys;
    /// <summary> Size of physical memory available, in bytes. </summary>
    public ulong ullAvailPhys;
    /// <summary> Size of the committed memory limit, in bytes. This is physical memory plus the size of the page file, minus a small overhead. </summary>
    public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
    /// <summary> Size of available memory to commit, in bytes. The limit is ullTotalPageFile. </summary>
    public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
    /// <summary> Total size of the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes. </summary>
    public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
    /// <summary> Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes. </summary>
    public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
    /// <summary> Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the extended portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes. </summary>
    public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
    /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of the MEMORYSTATUSEX class. </summary>
    public MEMORYSTATUSEX() => this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<MEMORYSTATUSEX>();
}

public static MEMORYSTATUSEX GetSystemMemoryStatus()
{
    var memoryStatus = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(memoryStatus);
    return memoryStatus;
}
```

Comment: You'll learn a lot more about the way computers work by digging into why "1000" seemed to be an appropriate way to "round".  It is not.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Do you mean because it it's not *precise* or because I, ahem, forgot mention that the Capacity  property is per MEMORY BANK?

Comment: It is, ahem, because you didn't research the discrepancy well enough.  You can google "why does totalphysicalmemory not match installed ram size" to get ahead.  Second hit is good, the noodling about the BIOS memory remapping feature tells you what's happening on your machine.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Updated with more informations. If you think I got it wrong, downvote, so I'll know.

Comment: FYI `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` can fail, e.g. in some virtual machines. One should check the returned bool to validate the response.

Comment: @dube If `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` fails it's because the SMBIOS information it gets is not valid or it doesn't match what `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` returns. In this case, `TotalMemoryInKilobytes` will be `0`, which is a good indication that the function failed. `GetLastError` doesn't give much information about it, just `ERROR_INVALID_DATA`. Reason why there are three method here to test these values, though one may want to use just `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`. The linked Docs explain how these functions behave a little more.

Comment: @Jimi I know, thanks. I just experienced this. It's intended to be a warning for future users, which will likely just blindly copy one of the three solutions. Both checking the value and the boolean works, the later being specifically mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @dube I've added a note about this and changed the code a bit. You made me remember that when `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` fails, the out value **may not** be `0`, but a *random number* instead, for some reason. I'm not sure if this still happens, but I'm relatively sure it could happen, in the past. So the C# method (renamed `GetTotalPhysicalInstalledMemory()`) returns `0` in case of failure.