# Win32_PhysicalMemory - Returning the total RAM size

Tags: c#

I have recently been creating an application that needs to read system information. I stumbled upon the Win32_PhysicalMemory class that gives me what I need, kinda. The code below returns multiple integers for the memory installed in each slot. I am attempting to combine the results to get a total but I keep hitting a wall. In the code below, I am using a string so it can be displayed but the method above will convert it accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks all!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ezCPU
{
    public class Memory
    {
        public string ramSize;
        public string ramType;

        //Take the returned RAM size and convert it to GB
        public string BytesToGB(string s)
        {
            double capacity = Convert.ToDouble(s);
            double newCapacity = capacity / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
            return Math.Round(newCapacity, 0).ToString() + " GB";
        }

        //Get all of the memory info
        public void GetRAMInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create the ManagementObjectSearcher grabbing everything from the Win32_PhysicalMemory
                ManagementObjectSearcher ram = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory");

                //Loop through the returned results
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in ram.Get())
                {
                    //Assign ram size
                    ramSize = obj["Capacity"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(BytesToGB(ramSize));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result in the console:

```
8 GB
8 GB
```

EDIT:
I know that I will more than likely have to use integers so that I can combine the two numbers and then perform the conversion but in my attempts to do that, it would combine the byte version of the size identically and not add them together.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has

Comment: See the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498549/7444103). Three methods (including the one you're using now), to compare the results.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I truly appreciate the help and that article explained everything flawlessly!

Comment: @Jimi I feel as if your answer was the best solution. How can I mark this as solved and choose your answer as the best solution to the problem at hand?

Comment: If you like/find useful an answer, you can just upvote it, or take the code, part of it, *refactor* it to fit a specific use case and post an answer yourself, adding a reference to the source. You, of course, shouldn't just take the code as it is and re-post it as an answer. You can also accept a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert the total supported memory using the Win32\_ComputerSystem class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496271/how-to-convert-the-total-supported-memory-using-the-win32-computersystem-class)  Just so it's spelled out here, the solution is to not calculate gigabytes and format as a `string` until _after_ you've summed the capacity of each memory module.

Comment: @BACON yes, that answered my question! Thanks again!